# Mask image thats too large for div css

Tags: jquery, css, image, html

I have a starburst image that needs to stay huge. I have it in a div box. The div box has constrained height and width. Yet the image still goes outside the div. How can I get it to cut off where ever?

You can see full example of what I'm trying to do here

http://jsfiddle.net/Cax9b/

Answer (score 4):

`overflow:hidden;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Cax9b/1/

Answer (score 1):

Set your div style to `overflow: hidden`.